# Copy specified range of cells from Excel to text using Python

Tags: python, excel, copy

I'm trying to copy the range of cells from Excel to text file, but I'm having a problem that the created .txt has far more rows than the Excel file from which the data is copied. It should have 2000 rows. Is there something wrong with this code? I also tried changing the range to (1, 2000) but it did not help.

This is the code I used

```
path = "E:\filename.xlsm"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
m_row = sheet_obj.max_row

for i in range(1, m_row + 1):
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=i, column=1)
    print(cell_obj.value)
    print(cell_obj.value, file=open(
        'E:\filename.txt',
        'a'))
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
The problem was not in the code, but the fact that the data was all the time added to the .txt file at the last line, rather than rewriten when the script was run.